# Prove that there exist constants such that $C_1|z-z_0|^{-m}\leq |f(z)|\leq C_2|z-z_0|^{-m}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, maximum-principle

> Prove that if $f$ has a pole of order $m$ in $z_0$, then there exist positive constants $r, C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
>   $$C_1|z-z_0|^{-m}\leq |f(z)|\leq C_2|z-z_0|^{-m}$$
>   for all $z\in D'(z_0;r)$.

What I did was first write $f$ as
$$f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-m}g(z)$$
where $f\in H(D(z_0;R))$ for some $R>0$ and $g(z_0)\neq 0$. Now, by the identity theorem, we can find sufficiently small $r<R$ such that $g(z)\neq 0$ for al $z\in D(z_0;r)$.

Now, $g$ is holomorphic on $D(z_0;r)$ and continuous on its boundary (since $g$ is also continuous on $D(z_0;R)$), so by the Maximum Modulus atheorem there is some $a\in \partial D(z_0;r)$ such that $|g(z)|\leq |g(a)|$ for all $z\in D(z_0;r)$. Letting $C_2=|g(a)|$
$$|f(z)|=|z-z_0|^{-m}|g(z)|\leq C_2|z-z_0|^{-m}$$

On the other hand, since $g(z)\neq 0$, $\frac{1}{g}$ is holomorphic in $D(z_0;r)$, somagain by the Maximum Modulus Theorem, there is some $b\in \partial D(z_0;r)$ such that $$ \frac{1}{|g(z)|}\leq \frac{1}{|g(b)|}$$
that is, $|g(b)|\leq |g(z)|$ for all $z\in D(z_0;r)$. Letting $C_1=|g(b)|$, we get the result.

Is this proof okay? I think I misused one of the theorems invoked above, but I'm not sure where or how. If not, how should I prove the result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine, just let me make some remarks:

- you have $g(z) \ne 0$ on $D(z_0, r)$ not by the identity theorem (which is like using a cannon to shoot birds), but by the continuity of $g$ on $D(z_0, R)$ and that fact that $g(z_0) \ne 0$; so, it's continuity, not analyticity, that you use here;
- a typo: in the sentence beginning with *"On the other hand"*, it is $g(z_0) \ne 0$, not $g(z) \ne 0$;

Comment: Thank you! Just one thing, the use of the identity Theorem is then wrong or just an overkill?

Comment: @user313212: In the current form, it's none of those two. I'd rater say that it's *cheating*, because you do not show *how* you use it. I could equally well say that the result follows from Lagrange's mean value theorem, without any justification (it doesn't!)... First, show me how you intend to use that theorem, and only then shall I be able to answer your question.

Comment: I think in class we saw this use of the identity theorem as a corollary (I can as well be mistaken) but I've been thinking and I haven't come up with a justification, if any. I think an argument by contradiction would suffice but I'm not able to prove it that way...